# Why does my test fail on verification of the mock function even though its been called already?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

So I am running the tests for my auth implementation in flutter and I seem to be getting a rather peculiar error. This is my test:

```
group('When remotedatabase calls signInWithGoogle', () {
group('and signs into google successfully', () {
  setUp(() {
    when(mockGoogleSignIn.signIn())
        .thenAnswer((realInvocation) async => mockGoogleSignInAccount);
  });
  test(
    'should return void if signin into firebase is successful',
    () async {
      // arrange

      when(mockFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(any))
          .thenAnswer((realInvocation) async => mockUserCredential);
      // act
      await remoteDatabaseImpl.signInWithGoogle();
      // assert
      verify(mockGoogleSignIn.signIn());
      //=> This verification passes <=//
      verify(mockFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(any));
    },
  );
  test(
    'should throw an authexception if unable to sign into firebase with credentials',
    () async {
      // arrange
      when(mockFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(any))
          .thenThrow(FirebaseAuthException(code: terror));
      // act
      final call = remoteDatabaseImpl.signInWithGoogle;

      // assert
      expectLater(call, throwsA(isA<AuthException>()));
      verify(mockGoogleSignIn.signIn());
      //=> This is the verification that fails <=//
      verify(mockFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(any));
    },
  );
});

 });
```

When I run the test, this is my output:

```
✓ When remotedatabase calls signInWithGoogle and signs into google successfully should return void if 
signin into firebase is successful
No matching calls (actually, no calls at all).
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)
package:test_api                                                                                 fail
_VerifyCall._checkWith
package:mockito/src/mock.dart:631
_makeVerify.<fn>
package:mockito/src/mock.dart:926
2
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
test\…\auth_data_sources\auth_remote_database_impl_test.dart:123
2

✖ When remote database calls signInWithGoogle and signs into google successfully should throw an 
auth exception if unable to sign into firebase with credentials
```

This is my implementation:

```
@override
Future<void> signInWithGoogle() async {
    AuthCredential authCredential;
    // signin with google first
    await googleSignIn.signIn().then(
          (GoogleSignInAccount googleAccount) async =>
              await googleAccount.authentication.then(
            (GoogleSignInAuthentication googleauth) async {
              authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                accessToken: googleauth.accessToken,
                idToken: googleauth.idToken,
              );
              // finally sign with firebaseauth
              try {
                await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
              } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                throw AuthException(e.code);
              }
            },
          ),
        );
    }
```

So as you can see the same verification seems to fail for different tests testing the same code implementation and I can't seem to figure the problem out. Please help.

Also, in the case for `await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);` does this function create an account for the credentials if it does not exist? Because I cannot seem to find a function like `await firebaseAuth.createAccountWithCredential(authCredential);` and I need to create an account for the google account if it's new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to await the expectLater:

```dart
expectLater(call, throwsA(isA<AuthException>()));
```

Also, if you want to catch errors like this in the future look in to the dart linting options. [unawaited_futures](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html) would have alerted you about this

As for the second part, yes it does create an account if the user doesnt have one yet.
This is also [documented on the function itself](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithCredential.html)

Comment:  you won't believe how long I have tried to debug such a tiny error

Comment: Before I accept the answer, can you please answer the 2nd question about the signinwithCredentials